# Can I have a field representing a constant in an interface that implementing classes can then set?

Tags: java

I've read that fields in interfaces can only ever represent constant values.  I'm confused by this.  Does it mean that the interface itself sets those values (the constant interface antipattern, which is bad) or that implementing classes can set their own values for the constant.

The latter would be useful if, say, I have a bunch of unrelated classes (unified by some common interface) and want to add some information about them.  For example:

```
public interface Animal
{
  public void walk()
}

public class Cat implements Animal
{
  public void walk() 
  {
    doCatWalk();
  }
}

public class Dog implements Animal
{
  public void walk()
  {
    doDogWalk();
  }
}
```

Now suppose I want to write a method that works on the noise that an `Animal` makes.  For that, I need to know what the noise is - it is a `String` variable, and is constant for a particular animal.  Could I change the interface to

```
public interface Animal
{
  public static final String NOISE;
  public void walk();
}
```

and, for example, implement `Cat` as:

```
public class Cat implements Animal
{
  public static final String NOISE = "Miaow!";
  public void walk()
  {
    doCatWalk();
  }
}
```

or is that not allowed?  I could, of course, use a getter instead, but the usual practice I've seen is to use `public static final` fields rather than `public` (implicitly static & final) getter methods for constants.

Comment: How can you not initialize a `static final` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Field declarations in interfaces are [implicitly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3) `public static final`. This

```
public interface Animal
{
    public static final String NOISE;
    public void walk();
}
```

won't work because you haven't initialized `NOISE`. Even if you did, fields are not overridable like methods. So

```
public class Cat implements Animal
{
    public static final String NOISE = "Miaow!";
    public void walk()
    {
        doCatWalk();
    }
    ...
}
```

Would just have its own `static NOISE` field which you could only access through a reference declared as `Cat`